# How to install and use docker in one shell script?

Tags: bash, docker, ray

I need to install docker and login to my repository in one script. I'm using ubuntu 16.04 but could also use 18.04.

docker_setup.sh:

```
sudo apt-get install -y docker.io
sudo service docker start
sudo usermod -a -G docker ubuntu
exec sudo su -l ubuntu
docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PW
```

This does not work in a shell script because the `sudo su` command opens up a subshell. I cannot do `newgrp docker` for the same reason. Also, I cannot do something like

```
newgrp docker << DOCKERSUBHSELL
docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PW
DOCKERSUBSHELL
```

because I am using the [ray library](https://github.com/ray-project/ray), and a later part of the library (that works under the hood) also expects to be able to use docker commands. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo su -l ubuntu -c "docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p '$DOCKER_PW'"` ?

Comment: The thing is, I need to still be able to use the docker command afterwards

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy. You can make a shell script exactly like this but you have to use cat and EOF. let me explain.

```
pi@raspberry$ sudo ./script.sh
```

This script will contain the following output

```
cat << EOF | sudo apt-get install -y docker.io
   sudo service docker start
   sudo usermod -a -G docker ubuntu
   exec sudo su -l ubuntu
   exit
   docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PW
   EOF
```

if this command "docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PW" is set to execute in ubuntu user then remove "exit" from my bash script and you are done.

Let me know if it works or the results so I can further modify it and help you. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be what's required :

```
sudo su -l ubuntu -c bash << DOCKERSUBSHELL
    docker login -u "$DOCKER_USER" -p "$DOCKER_PW"
DOCKERSUBSHELL
```